# Can adding a solution to TFS server cause WCF to break?

Tags: wcf, tfs, azure, codeplex, visual-studio-2010

I am running on SP1 beta of 2010... it may or may not related to the beta.  But, in general, can adding a project to the codeplex TFS server somehow make WCF break when also inside an Azure project?

Seems to be the pattern for me.  Immediately upon launch I get a ServicePoint exception.  If I remove the app from source control everything works fine.

My project consists of

1. Azure WCF hello world application
2. VS2010 SP1 beta
3. Adding codeplex TFS reference causes exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a CommunicationFaultedException? If it is, it is a bug when working with Azure 1.3 SDK projects that are checked into TFS. Make sure you have the Web.config file checked out (writeable).

If not, can you give any other information on on the ServicePoint execption?

Comment: Does that mean only one developer can debug at a time?  Only one checkout of web.config right?

Comment: Sounds more like an Azure bug, brought on by the fact that TFS is marking the non-checked-out file as read-only.

Comment: More than one dev can debug at the same time. Right-click the Web.config file and Check Out for Edit. Everyone will have the file checked out, but no one should be making changes to it. Link to MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/26165c71-f941-4d84-9ef3-649d7bab0066