# Azure Role state Unhealthy when using TFS

Tags: tfs, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I tried to run an ASP.NET MVC 3 application on the development fabric of Windows Azure on my local machine. I followed the steps found on the following website: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/asp-net-mvc-in-windows-azure

I did everything exactly as mentioned in the tutorial. 
Everything worked well.

I then added the Visual Studio Solution to Team Foundation Server and wanted to run the application but nothing works. The Windows Azure Compute Emulation states that the Azure Role state is unhealthy. 
Internet Explorer does not open with the application (as it did before).
I can therefore not run the application anymore. I did not change anything at the code or the configuration.

I am new to TFS (2010) and installed it on a my local machine (Windows 7) with the basic configuration. I used the default values of the installation.

Does anybody know why this runs when I create a normal solution that is not connected to TFS and suddenly stops working when adding the solution to TFS?

Greetings

Alexander

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can adding a solution to TFS server cause WCF to break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763369/can-adding-a-solution-to-tfs-server-cause-wcf-to-break)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else mentioned that there can be a problem when the web.config is not writeable. Check out this answer and see if it is what you are experiencing.

[Can adding a solution to TFS server cause WCF to break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763369/can-adding-a-solution-to-tfs-server-cause-wcf-to-break)